# Parse iOS-XCode6: problems with PFUser objects from AnyPic using storyboards

Tags: ios, storyboard, parse-platform, xcode6, pfuser

I am Trying to add the **USER** structure from **AnyPic tutorial** into my app.
I had several problems compiling the project on XCode6.

Finally I solved all of them (arm64 architectures problems, MBProgressHUD, TTTTimeIntervalFormatter, ParseSDK framework, etc..) and I got all the classes I need on my app without compile errors.

I've implemented a FB Login structure on my main View Controller, so I didn't use the Parse Facebook Login methods (I didn't import in my project Login methods and classes).

I am interested on the USER structure with Fb profile picture, following/followers methods and view controllers for Account Settings and Timeline, basically the 2 classes *PAPAccountViewController* and *PAPHomeViewController* both subclasses of *PAPPhotoTimelineViewControllers*.
*PAPPhotoTimelineViewController* never displayed on its own, but rather inherited by the main timeline and the user account view controllers.

- Here it is the interface for ACCOUNT SETTINGS View Controller I want to achieve (*PAPAccountViewController* class) : https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/86526597/anypic-tutorial/profile.png

### MAIN PROBLEM:

**AnyPic do not use Storyboards** and I can't handle with PFUser *user object because I didn't understand where the USER initialization is.

I am trying to connect the *PAPAccountViewController* in a TableViewController on my Storyboard.
This is the error I get:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'user cannot    be nil'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x185a67100 0x1924441fc 0x185a67040 0x1000941b4 0x188a30658 0x188a303dc 0x188bdd850 0x188ae7f3c     0x188ae7d0c 0x188ae7c8c 0x188a2afe0 0x18861c258 0x188616e20 0x188616cd8 0x188616560 0x188616304 0x188a2f154 0x185a277f4 0x185a26b50 0x185a24de8 0x185965dd0 0x18b605c0c 0x188a96fc4 0x1000dfffc 0x192a37aa0)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

//  PAPAccountViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

if (!self.user) {
    [NSException raise:NSInvalidArgumentException format:@"user cannot be nil"];
}
```

In order to Test if something shows up I also did a reference from the TableViewController on my storyboard to the superclass "PAPPhotoTimelineViewControllers", which is a subclass of *PFQueryTableViewController*, and it worked fine.

An empty TableViewController load after running, and I think it'ok because the class never displayed on its own.

But nothing load for PAPAccountViewController.

How can I solve this?
I do not have users on my Parse Database and it obviously throws the exception, but I couldn't find where the PFUser object is initialized.

- Maybe the PFUser object comes from the Login Fb with Parse?
  I tried to use Parse for Facebook login before but it doesn't work for XCode6.
- Does my way to proceed with Storyboards make sense?

Here it is the tutorial and the link for the code:
https://parse.com/tutorials/anypic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question solved, i found my own solution by optimizing Anypic tutorial for Xcode6 then adopting storyboards with code views and my classes!